# Finding a sequence of step-functions to represent integrals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, step-function

Find a sequence of step functions $ψ_n : [0, 1] → R$ $(n ∈ N)$ that satisfy $\int_0^1 ψ_n(t) \, dt >0$ and

$$\int_0^1 ψ_n (t)\,dt/\|ψ_n\|_∞ → 0 \text{ as } n→∞$$

I'm not really sure how to start here. From logic, these criteria imply that the area under the curve of the step functions need to be positive but can't infer much other than that. I appreciate it's a simple question but any help is welcome!

Comment: Don't overthink this. How about using triangles whose heights get large and whose areas stay constant?

Comment: @Matematleta I'm sure it is relatively simple and once it clicks it'll be easy for me, but I'm unsure on the whole concept. I know what a step function looks like and why they can be used to find integrals of functions, but not much else.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. You shouldn't alternate in and out of MathJax in the course of writing one expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this $\psi_{n}(x)=\chi_{[0,1/n^{2}]}(x)$ do the job?

Comment: Potentially, but can you breifely explain why this works and what the $χ$ means please?

Comment: The indicator function, $1$ on that interval, and zero otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, and why does this step function sequence work?

Comment: Apparently $\|\phi_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}=1$. But then the integral is simply $1/n^{2}$.

Comment: I think I understand. So the bottom equals 1 as thats the biggest it can be, whilst the top is convergent, which means that the whole thing tends to 0?

Comment: The top converges to zero, not only convergent. Anyway, convergence doesn't imply convergence to zero, your wording may sound a little misleading.

Comment: Yep my bad poor wording. Thanks though